# How do I change the standard create button in ODOO

Tags: javascript, python, field, odoo, dropdown

In tree view or in form view for my particular model, i want to change the create button.
It is necessary that when you click on it a dropdown appears with selection or many2one. As in the screenshot.

[image]

my code:

```
`    <record id="student_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Create button this</field>
            <field name="res_model">school.student</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <!-- <field name="search_view_id" ref="student_search_view"/>
            <field name="context">{'search_default_male': 1}</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field> -->
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Create The First Student
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>    `
```

I know you need to use js. And you need to use it somehow List.View.Buttons for override Standard Rendering and Actions.

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Comment: @MickaelB. added to the question